# 'Undefined function or variable' in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Here is my code:

```
    function [im,sindx,end1]=alln(im,i,j,secret,sindx,end1)
    slen=length(secret);
    p=im(i,j);
    neigh= [im(i-1,j) im(i+1,j) im(i,j-1) im(i,j+1) im(i-1,j-1) im(i+1,j-1) im(i-1,j+1) im(i+1,j+1)];
    minpix = min (neigh)
    maxpix = max (neigh)

        if minpix < p < maxpix
        lowlim = minpix+1;
        highlim = maxpix-1;   
        range = highlim-lowlim+1;

        nbits=floor(log2(abs(range)));   

        if sindx+nbits-1>slen
            end1=1;
            return
        end
        for k=1:nbits
            bin(k)=secret(sindx+k-1);
        end
        b = bin2dec(bin);
        newvalue1 = abs (minpix + b);
        newvalue2 = abs (maxpix - b);
        if abs(p-newvalue1)<= abs(p-newvalue2)
            im(i,j) = newvalue1;
        else
            im(i,j) = newvalue2;
        end

        sindx=sindx+nbits;

    end
end
```

My main program calls this function. When I run the program, I get the following error message:

```
??? Undefined function or variable "bin".

Error in ==> alln at 34
            b = bin2dec(bin);
```

I know there are many experts for whom this is not a problem at all. I am new to MATLAB. Please guys, show me the way, which type of modification in the code can overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, are there some lines missing from the file?  Perhaps you've stripped some comments from the top?  Because the error message says that

```
b = bin2dec(bin);
```

is line 34, but it's line 22 in the code you present.

OK, that aside...

The error message says that 'bin' isn't defined, but I see that it's being set on the line...

```
bin(k)=secret(sindx+k-1);
```

That suggests to me that THAT line isn't being run.

I see that that bin = ... line is inside of a 'for' loop, so I suspect that the for loop is run zero times, meaning that 'bin' never gets defined.  What is nbits?  Is it 1, or perhaps less than 1?  THAT would prevent the loop from running at all.

Try removing the semicolon from the end of the

```
nbits=floor(log2(abs(range)));
```

line and run your code again.

Leaving off the semicolon will force the value of nbits to be printed in the Command Window.  I bet you'll find that it's 1 or less.  If that's the case, then start looking at HOW nbits is calculated, and I bet you'll find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

At what input arguments to the function `alln`, are you getting the error?

Lets suppose that `nbits` is 0, then the following loop will not run:

```
for k=1:nbits
    bin(k)=secret(sindx+k-1);
end
```

So, `bin` will be undefined. So, the error happens. This is one of the cases where the error can happen. There are many such possible cases.

Comment: Another question Neeraj, How can I enter into Debug Mode. I mean I want to run my program by using the 'Step', 'Step In' etc. But the options are disabled in my program. How can I enable them?